# Regular Expression Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guys I have looked a many versions of regular expression validation but I can not get it to work where it will only allow a certain letters at the beginning before anymore text is entered therefore if that text is not entered then nothing can be entered as it will show validation. For example I have tried:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^(?:[www.]|a-z|A-Z|)*$", /*This allows the www. only and nothing else*/ ErrorMessage = "Cars Only")]
public string Cars { get; set; }
```

and i have tried:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^(?:(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)|a-z|A-Z|)*$", /*This does not work*/
ErrorMessage = "Cars Only")]
public string Cars { get; set; }
```

Many others also but to much paste will become to long.

Can any help so after the `www.` anything can be typed in but if no `www.` is entered then it will show error message.

Comment: What happened to my tags I was able to use Razor.asp.net as a tag and Razor webpages as a tag but no longer can I am using Razor in asp.net I should have access to them tags thanks for editing I tried to get it like that but my browser wouldn't let me thanks

Comment: what problem are you solving? Many websites have a url that doesn't start with `www.`.

Comment: The problem is solved my dear friend thanks to you when i create a question on this website I can no longer chose the tags which were available to me such as: Razor.asp.net and Razor webpages these were available to me when I use to add questions and now they have been removed from my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"www." matching:

```
www\..* // no line start/end criteria
^www\..*$ // line start/end enforced
```

Here's a more comprehensive expression that handles the prefix:

```
^(https?|ftp):\/\/www\..*$
```

This will match:

```
http://www.test.com 
https://www.test.com 
ftp://www.test.com/test
```

Better still, this makes the prefix mandatory, but the "www." optional:

```
^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/(www\.)?.*$
```

This will match:

```
http://www.test.com
https://www.test.com
ftp://www.test.com/test
http://test.com
https://test.com
ftp://foo.org
```

Matching images only

```
^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/(www\.)?.*\/[\w\-\+\%]*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$
```

This will match:

```
ftp://foo.org/test.png
https://test.com/image.jpg
http://www.bar.com/my-image.png
http://foo.org/my%20image.jpeg
http://foo.org/my%20image%20test_foo.jpeg
```

This will require a prefix at the beginning, a forward slash, a file name (which allows alphanumeric characters, underscores, dashes, and URL encoded values containing % or +) and a valid image extension.

**This will not be foolproof! Remember that images can be served from any HTTP handler. The URL might have nothing image-related in it.**

**Additional Information**

I agree with @Russ Cam's suggestion to look at the [jQuery validator source code](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.js) to see how many possibilities there are actually are.

It's possible that URL the user enters is in a valid form but doesn't exist; this could be checked server-side with a simple request.

I recommend [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) if you often need to create regular expressions.

I also recommend [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr) for quick online testing.

Comment: How would I do this so it takes in any URL? or better still an image only? as this field on my website allows a filed for a image for which allows a user to copy a url and put it in and it displays the image

Comment: But it allows any website in. Is there a way to allow the second one with images

Comment: @user1137472 - See my update for a regex which will match image URL formats.

Comment: Thanks this field that I have only should allow images from online websites shall try and a reply thanks alot

Comment: Thank You sir you are a genius in your field have a very nice evening you have helped a handful thank you so much

Comment: may i have the website that you got this code from? or did you create it your self? if you have created it yourself then may I apologizes for saying that you may have got this from a url

Comment: Of course a url might point to an image, but not end in a image-extension, and the other way round.

Comment: @user1137472 - I just quickly wrote that for you. I've added some additional information to my post around tools/recommendations.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - agreed, hence my warning in bold letters that the URL may give no indication that it serves an image, like `http://foo.com?x=0`. I usually err on the side of lighter client validation and use the server to validate via a real request. But the OP was looking for a specific expression.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys I am truly blessed to join such a community thanks

Comment: Hi guys I have a problem ^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/(www\.)?.*\/[\w\-\+\%]*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ this code works but when i remove teh url in the image input box and edit undo it says it needs the correct format but when i refresh the page it allows the image to be placed

Comment: @user1137472 - you should open this as a new question so everyone can see it. This sounds like a problem with the validation, not the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

according to your criteria,

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^www\..+$", ErrorMessage = "Cars Only")]
public string Cars { get; set; }
```

You can play with this regex on [**nregex**](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx) to see what is matched and what isn't.

I suspect your looking for Regular Expression to match a valid URI? If you are, I would use a regex for the client side (take a look at the url rule in **[jQuery validate](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.js)**) and create a Validation attribute for the server side that passes the string into [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(string uri, UriKind.Absolute)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)

Comment: I am using MVC3 but i cant include that in my tags this is not compatible with MVC3 it says the "." is not recognized

Comment: D'oh! forgot the `@` prefix for a verbatim string literal. Try it now

Comment: It works but I wanted it for a website you see the thing is now It needs www. But the code works fine not what I wanted Thank you for the code

Comment: @user1137472 that's exactly the requirement that you put in your question: `Can any help so after the www. anything can be typed in but if no www. is entered then it will show error message.` In the regex above, the input must start with `www.` or will show error message. If that's not what you need, you can edit your question to clarify :)

Comment: You would think www. means a url for a website I know your programmers at a very high standard and i respect your work but not using common sense to see that www. refers to a URL address is a bit silly dont you think? Just allowing the www. that's not a URL its 3 letters

Answer (score 0):

Split up the required parts (i.e. make the `www.` optional, and then what follows it optional but not dependent on the `www.`

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^(?:[www.])(?:|a-z|A-Z|)*$", /*This allows the www. only and nothing else*/ ErrorMessage = "Cars Only")]
public string Cars { get; set; }
```

Comment: was trying to find one for url but couldn't do you know any?

Comment: This does not work when i put this in after the www. I cant include anything

Comment: I could expand, but I'd suggest going with Tim's answer above!